# Converting formula variables to variable names with regex operations

Tags: python, regex, list, split, python-re

I ma trying to convert the variable `Formula_bit` into variable like names where they are lowercase and words are seperated by `_`. My Process is as follows splitting the right-hand side by operators (+, -, *, /) or x (multiplication), converts the resulting items to lowercase, replaces spaces with underscores, removes opening and closing parentheses. Finally removing the  leading and trailing underscores if there are any. However my `output` and `expected outputs` dont match what could I do to fix this?

```
import re 
Formula_bit = ['Σ (Dividends)', 'Dividend Payout Ratio * eps']

# Process the right-hand side of each formula to extract parameters
params = [
    re.split(r'\s*[+\-*/]\s*| x ', re.sub(r'[+\-*/]', ',', item))[0]  # Split the right-hand side by operators (+, -, *, /) or 'x' (multiplication)
        .lower()  # Convert to lowercase
        .replace(" ", "_")  # Replace spaces with underscores
        .replace("(", "")  # Remove opening parentheses
        .replace(")", "")  # Remove closing parentheses 
    for item in Formula_bit
]

# Remove leading and trailing underscores from each item and strip whitespace
params = [item.lstrip('_').rstrip('_').strip() for item in params]
```

Output:

```
['σ_dividends', 'dividend_payout_ratio_,_eps']
```

Expected output:

```
['σ_dividends', 'dividend_payout_ratio', 'eps']
```

Comment: Why do you substitute the operators by commas? If you make that substitution first, you won't have where to split later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example, that converts formula to variable names

```py
import re
import string

Formula_bit = ['Σ (Dividends)', 'Dividend Payout Ratio * eps']  # Input formulas

splitter = "_"  # Splitter character for replacing spaces
formula = ",".join(Formula_bit)  # Join the formulas into a single string
formula = re.sub(r"[()]", "", formula.lower())  # Remove parentheses from the formula string
formula = re.sub(r"\s", splitter, formula)  # Replace whitespace characters with the splitter
punctuation = string.punctuation.replace(splitter, "")  # Punctuation excluding the splitter
formula = re.sub(fr"[{punctuation}]", ",", formula)  # Remove punctuation characters from the formula strin
params = [s.strip(splitter) for s in formula.split(",")]  # Split the formula string on commas to extract the parameters and strip splitter characters
print(params)
# ['σ_dividends', 'dividend_payout_ratio', 'eps']
```

Here one check is missed. To be a valid variable name, first character should be a letter (not digit).